# Oracle error ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: oracle10g

here's the stored procedure i wrote.In this proc "p_subjectid" is an array of numbers passed from the front end.

```
PROCEDURE getsubjects(p_subjectid subjectid_tab,p_subjects out refCursor) 
       as

       BEGIN

            open p_subjects for select * from empsubject where subject_id in
            (select column_value from table(p_subjectid));
            --select * from table(cast(p_subjectid as packg.subjectid_tab))
      END getsubjects;
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
Oracle error ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item OR
```

as i have seen in different post,i tried casting "cast(p_subjectid as packg.subjectid_tab)" inside table function as given in the comment below.But i am getting another error: `ORA-00902: invalid datatype`.

And this is the definition of the "subjectid_tab".

```
type subjectid_tab is table of number index by binary_integer;
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the error.Is anything wrong with the my procedure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to declare the type on "the database level" as ammoQ suggested:

```
CREATE TYPE subjectid_tab AS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY binary_integer;
```

instead of declaring the type within PL/SQL. If you declare the type just in the PL/SQL block, it won't be available to the SQL "engine".

Comment: This doesn't work in Oracle 11g, in case anyone else is struggling..  PLS-00355: Use of pl/sql table not defined in this context.  Everything looks good in Oracle 12c though.  As a work around in 11g, if you can only bind to associative arrays (like nodejs), I've been looping my associative array into a nested table (no INDEX BY suffix) first; which kills the performance, but what can you do?  If someone knows a better way, don't hesitate to reach out.

Comment: This answer is half-right and half-wrong - `TYPE ... AS TABLE OF ... INDEX BY ...` is an associative array and a PL/SQL data type - it cannot be used in the SQL scope and cannot be defined using `CREATE TYPE` but you are correct that to use the type in an SQL statement that type needs to be defined in the SQL scope and not the PL/SQL scope (its just an associative array will not work).

Answer (score 3):

Oracle has two execution scopes: SQL and PL/SQL. When you use a `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE` (etc) statement you are working in the SQL scope and, in Oracle 11g and below, you cannot reference types that are defined in the PL/SQL scope. (*Note: Oracle 12 changed this so you can reference PL/SQL types.)*

```
TYPE subjectid_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Is an associative array and can only be defined in the PL/SQL scope so cannot be used in SQL statements.

What you want is to define a collection (not an associative array) in the SQL scope using:

```
CREATE TYPE subjectid_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

(*Note: you do not need the `INDEX BY` clause for a collection.*)

Then you can do:

```
OPEN p_subjects FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   empsubject
  WHERE  subject_id MEMBER OF p_subjectid;
```

or

```
OPEN p_subjects FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   empsubject
  WHERE  subject_id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( p_subjectid ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem yesterday.

```
DECLARE 
  TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  result_ids number_table := number_table();
BEGIN
  /* .. bunch of code that uses my type successfully */ 

  OPEN ? AS 
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(CAST(result_ids AS number_table)); /* BOOM! */
END;
```

This fails in both of the ways you described earlier when called from a java routine. I discovered this was due to the fact that the type number_table is not defined in an exportable manner than can be shipped off the database. The type works great internally to the routine. But as soon as you try to execute a returnable recordset that references it in any way (including IN clauses?!?) you get a datatype not defined.

So the solution really is `CREATE TYPE myschema.number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER;` Then drop the type declaration from your block and use the schema level declaration. Use the schema qualifier to reference the type just to be sure you are using the right one.

Answer (score 2):

This is the good solution.
You cannot use a table(cast()) if the type that you cast is in the DECLARE part of the pl/sql block.
You REALLY need to use CREATE TYPE my_type [...]. Otherwise, it will throw the "cannot fetch row[...]" exception.

Comment: This is half the answer - unfortunately you cannot use `CREATE TYPE` in the SQL scope with an associative array (`AS TABLE OF ... INDEX BY ...`) as it is a PL/SQL data type. You also need to remove the `INDEX BY` clause so the type is a collection (not an associative array).

Answer (score 1):

you have to cast the results of the pipelined query so:

If your pipelined function returns a rowtype of varchar2 then define a type (for example )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE char_array_t is VARRAY(32) of varchar2(255);
select * from table(cast(fn(x) as user_type_t ) );
```

will now work.