# ORA-22905 on setting Count(*) into out param

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've created a sample oracle function to returns the number of records in a table. Here is it

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEST_COUNT
RETURN NUMBER AS recCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO recCount  FROM **tableName**;
  return recCount;
END TEST_COUNT;
```

Its' being compiled successfully, but when I called this function in **Oracle SQL-Developr** using command

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (TEST_COUNT());
```

it threw me the following error.

```
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
*Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
           parse time or that is not of a nested table type
*Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type
Error at Line: 1 Column: 22
```

I've followed [Oracle error ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896356/oracle-error-ora-22905-cannot-access-rows-from-a-non-nested-table-item) but can't reach the solution. Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from that code? It looks fine, unless `**tableName**` is something weird. What else is in the same script, as that isn't 19 lines long? The function isn't created at all; or it's created with compilations errors; or it's created successfully and you get an error calling it? If it's when you call, how are you doing that?

Comment: @AlexPoole, the function is correct and not giving any compilation errors. Replace **tableName** with name of the table in your database.

Comment: So when do you get the error - how are you calling it? What is line 19 of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're just calling it wrong. The [`TABLE()` table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30047) is used when the function returns a collection (e.g. from `create type x as table of number`) that you want to treat as a table so you can join against it, which isn't the case here; you're returning a simple `NUMBER`.

So just do:

```
SELECT TEST_COUNT FROM DUAL;
```