# How can use array type in where clause of update statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I want a procedure get a list of disabling privilege, and update their record in table. For doing this scenario, I defined an array as database object with below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_DISABLE_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER(32)
```

Then I defined an input parameter in procedure signature, and got passed value.

```
PROCEDURE PRC_ROLE_PRIVILAGE_MANAGEMENT(P_REQ_USER_ID    IN VARCHAR2,
                                        P_DISABLE_LIST   IN T_DISABLE_LIST,
                                        P_RES_DESC       OUT VARCHAR2)
BEGIN
    UPDATE T_ PRIVILAGE p
       SET P.ENABLE_STATUS = 0, P.GRANT_USERID = P_REQ_USER_ID
    WHERE P.ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(P_DISABLE_LIST));

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RES_DESC := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1, 400);
END;
```

This procedure will be compile successfully. But when I test it, I got this error:

> ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Any body can help me? And say why this code don't work correctly?

And finally, how can i resolve this problem?

P.S: My orcale version is 9.2!!!

Comment: Is your custom TYPE declared at database level? If you declare it in PL/SQL, you receive this error because the database engine doesn't know the type. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896356/oracle-error-ora-22905-cannot-access-rows-from-a-non-nested-table-item)

Comment: Dear @ThomasG , Yes I defined it in database level (as database object)

Answer (score 2):

**This assumes you are using Oracle 10g or later (and was written before the OP clarified what version they are using)**

Use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```
UPDATE T_PRIVILAGE
SET    ENABLE_STATUS = 0,
       GRANT_USERID  = P_REQ_USER_ID
WHERE  ID MEMBER OF P_DISABLE_LIST;
```

You can also use the `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudo-column:

```
UPDATE T_PRIVILAGE
SET    ENABLE_STATUS = 0,
       GRANT_USERID  = P_REQ_USER_ID
WHERE  ID IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( P_DISABLE_LIST ) );
```

> why this code does not work correctly?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE( P_DISABLE_LIST )
```

Is selecting the row from the table. However, the table is generated by a table collection expression and there is no underlying database table to reference a row of so Oracle generates an `ORA-22905` exception.(there would be an underlying table if the collection was stored in a nested table; which is why that situation is specifically mentioned in the exception).

**Update**: PL/SQL solution:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. P_DISABLE_LIST.COUNT LOOP
  UPDATE T_PRIVILAGE
  SET    ENABLE_STATUS = 0,
         GRANT_USERID  = P_REQ_USER_ID
  WHERE  ID = P_DISABLE_LIST(i);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Your answer not work. with **first solution**, code didn't compile, and I got this error `"ORA-00920: invalid relational operator"`. and with **2nd solution**, i got this error `"ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"`

Comment: @M.i.T That is something very important that you need to put into your question as, without it, we will assume that you are using a version released in the last decade - not one that is almost from last century.

Comment: @M.i.T I have added a PL/SQL solution that may work but I do not have an Oracle 9i instance to test it on.

Comment: Dear @MT0, You are right. I forgot it. I apologize... And This application is very old, and i must to support it :'(